# hbox does not fit borderpane top

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

My hbox does not fit into my top borderpane.
I dynamically entered my hbox like this:

```
URL hBoxUrl = getClass().getResource("/gui/views/HamburgerMenu.fxml");           
loader.setLocation(hBoxUrl);
HBox hBox = loader.load();
```

`rootLayout.setTop(hBox);`

Is there any solution so that my hbox will fit my top borderpane? Can I do it via scenebuilder or by code? 
Here is what it looks like:
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's your `HBox` that doesn't fit the top and not just a child of the `HBox`? The latter could be avoided by using `HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"` on the child.

Comment: @fabian hi there, yes its the HBox since the child would be the jfxHamburger button. Would you know any solution on how I can fit it to the border pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is the `maxWidth="595.0"` attribute in your `<JFXHamburger...>` element. Just remove it and `HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"` will work as expected.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXHamburger?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <top>
        <HBox>
            <JFXHamburger HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" style="-fx-background-color: lightblue;">
                <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="15.0" right="15.0" top="5.0" />
                </padding>
            </JFXHamburger>
        </HBox>
    </top>
    <center>
        <Pane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="800.0">

        </Pane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

[image]

Comment: I removed maxWidth="-Infinity" and minWidth="-Infinity" and then it worked. Thank you for the clue. Without your answer I wouldn't have found this. Thank you.